# Chamar outra tela apos alguns segundos sem interação do usuário

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Estou precisando colocar no meu app o seguinte comportamento:

Após alguns segundos sem que usuário toque na tela, por exemplo 10 segundos, o app apresente uma outra tela mostrando uma imagem. E quando o usuário toque na tela, a tela da imagem desapareça e volte para a tela anterior. E enquanto o usuário estiver interagindo com o app não aparecer nada.

O comportamento será parecido como o de uma proteção de tela.

Comment: Não existe coisa mais irritante para um usuário do que estas telas que surgem do nada sem serem solicitadas.
Um principio básico de desenvolvimento diz que não se deve apresentar nada que não tenha sido solicitado pelo usuário.
Se você quer que o usuário exerça uma ação após decorrido dez segundos, diga isso a ele na própria interface e não fazendo aparecer uma tela popup. A própria proteção de tela é uma opção do usuário e não uma imposição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você também pode usar o métodos do `UIResponder` que o seu `AppDelegate` herda.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    // Ao detectar o toque, reseta o timer
    [self resetarTimerDeInatividade];
}

- (void)resetarTimerDeInatividade {
    if (self.interacaoTimer) {
        // Caso o timer esteja ativo, invalidamos ele
        [self.interacaoTimer invalidate];
        self.interacaoTimer = nil;
    }

    NSInteger tempoMaximoSemInteracao = 10; // em segundos

    // Iniciamos o timer novamente
    self.interacaoTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:tempoMaximoSemInteracao
                                                           target:self
                                                             selector:@selector(tempoInativoExcedido)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
}

- (void)tempoInativoExcedido{
    // Aqui você pode disparar a exibição da sua tela temporária
}
```

Comment: Vou testar seu código e já trago a resposta se ele funcionou ou não!

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução possível é utilizar um timer que é resetado a cada interação do usuário. Quando o limite de tempo é atingido, o timer chamará o selector especificado:

```
- (void)resetTimer {

    if (timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
}

- (UIResponder *)nextResponder {

    [self resetTimer];
    return [super nextResponder];
}
```

Você pode usar o método `viewDidAppear` para iniciar o timer.

Comment: Vou tentar o seu codigo e trarei a resposta!! Obrigado @Rafael Leão

Comment: o método viewDidAppear não está mais disponível para iOS 7, ou estou enganado? 

 Será que não posso fazer em didViewLoad??

Comment: O método `viewDidAppear:` ainda continua disponível no iOS 7.

Comment: @Rafael Leão Seu código funciona, mas apresenta o seguinte erro quando a view que eu quero entra na tela:

Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController: 0x8c8dec0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: Estou usando modal transiction para fazer a tela que eu quero aparecer e dissmis para remover ela quando a tela é tocada.